# Magento 2: How to generate backend url with key from frontend?

Tags: magento2, url

I need to generate backend url with key like this:

```
https://m2.com/admin/test/test/index/key/123XXXX
```

using URL builder

```
$this->getUrl('test/test/index')
```

how can i achieve this from the frontend side ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstand your question. You want to generate a backend url and access it from frontend site, right?

In your `Controller/Block` class, inject `\Magento\Backend\Model\Url`

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Url $backendUrl,
    ...
) {
    parent::__construct(...);
    $this->backendUrl = $backendUrl;
}
```

So you can achieve your url simply like this

```
// Output http://magento2.url/admin/test/test/index/key/123XXX/
$this->backendUrl->getUrl('test/test/index', ['key' => '123XXX']);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $HelperBackend;
protected $urlBuilder;

public function __construct(
    ............................................
    \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $HelperBackend,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    ............................................
) {
    ............................................
    $this->HelperBackend = $HelperBackend;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    ............................................
}

public function getCustomUrlAdmin()
{
    $admin_name = $this->HelperBackend->getAreaFrontName();
    $link = $admin_name . "/test/test/index/";
    $custom_link = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($link);
    return $custom_link;
}
```